# I want my grid to appear exactly the same as jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, button, grid

I have a hyperlink (open grid) where if user clicks on it it opens up a grid of buttons. What I want to know does anyone know to code it so that except for the grid of button being displayed below the textbox, if the grid of buttons can be hovered over the (open grid) link.

In other words I want it to work exactly the same as Jquery datepicker where if you click over the calender icon the calender displays like a hover below the calender icon and text box.

The datepicker jquery example I am referring to is this link here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

My code is in jsfiddle.net: click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrxfs/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you speak about the fadeIn/fadeOut effect. You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jrxfs/11/

Added fadeIn/fadeOut using :

- `$('#optionTypeTbl').fadeIn('slow');`
- `$('#optionTypeTbl').fadeOut('slow');`

**EDIT :** Added `position:absolute;` and `background-color:white;` on `#optionTypeTbl`. Check the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jrxfs/11/

Comment: Hi, that is a good effect, my only issue is that if there is anything below the grid, then what happens is that it moves everything below the grid down, what I want is the grid to fade over the other aspects below the grid rather than pushing them down. I have updated my jsfiddle so that you can see what I mean. Thank You